# Vending Machine

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns, .net, console

After doing a lot of reading and practicing, I've come up with a simple program that implements multiple OOP techniques, principles and several design patterns such as Observers, Factories and Singletons.

The program represents a vending machine with all the relevant actions and properties. The vending machine can be refilled with items, a client can purchase a specific item, the machine screen notifies the client about the result of his actions etc'.

**VendingMachine.cs**

```
public sealed class VendingMachine : ObserverCommands
{
    private static VendingMachine instance;

    private readonly Dictionary<Item, int> machineItems;
    private readonly Stack<SaleRecord> saleRecords;
    private double machineBank;
    private List<Observer> machineObservers;

    private VendingMachine()
    {
        this.machineItems = new Dictionary<Item, int>();
        this.saleRecords = new Stack<SaleRecord>();
        this.machineBank = 0;
        this.machineObservers = new List<Observer>();
    }

    public static VendingMachine GetInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new VendingMachine();
        return instance;
    }
    public double MachineBank
    {
        get
        {
            return this.machineBank;
        }
    }
    public Dictionary<Item, int> MachineItems
    {
        get
        {
            return this.machineItems;
        }
    }
    public Stack<SaleRecord> SaleRecords
    {
        get
        {
            return this.saleRecords;
        }
    }

    public List<SaleRecord> GetLastSaleRecords(int num)
    {
        List<SaleRecord> list;

        if(num <= 0)
            return null;

        list = new List<SaleRecord>();

        foreach (SaleRecord saleRecord in saleRecords)
        {
            list.Add(saleRecord);
            if (--num == 0)
                break;
        }

        return list;
    }
    public int GetItemStock(Item item)
    {
        if (machineItems.ContainsKey(item))
            return machineItems[item];

        return -1;
    }
    public int GetTotalMachineItems()
    {
        int totalItems = 0;
        foreach (Item item in machineItems.Keys)
            totalItems += machineItems[item];
        return totalItems;

    }

    public void RefillItems()
    {
        machineItems.Clear();
        this.machineItems.Add(ItemFactory.GetItem("Coca Cola 330"), 20);
        this.machineItems.Add(ItemFactory.GetItem("Coca Cola Zero 330"), 20);
        this.machineItems.Add(ItemFactory.GetItem("Fuze Tea 500"), 20);
        this.machineItems.Add(ItemFactory.GetItem("Pepsi Max 330"), 20);
        this.machineItems.Add(ItemFactory.GetItem("Pepsi Max 500"), 10);
        this.machineItems.Add(ItemFactory.GetItem("Evian 500"), 10);
        this.machineItems.Add(ItemFactory.GetItem("Lays Barbecue"), 3);
        this.machineItems.Add(ItemFactory.GetItem("Lays Sour Cream & Onion"), 1);

        NotifyAllObservers(new VendingMachineLog("Machine has been refilled."));
    }
    public void SellItem(Item item, double amountPaid)
    {
        machineBank += item.ItemPrice;
        machineItems[item]--;
        NotifyAllObservers(new VendingMachineLog("Item has been sold."));
    }
    public void AddSaleRecord(SaleRecord saleRecord)
    {
        this.saleRecords.Push(saleRecord);
        NotifyAllObservers(new VendingMachineLog("Sale Record Added"));
    }

    public void RegisterObserver(Observer observer)
    {
        this.machineObservers.Add(observer);
    }
    public void UnregisterObserver(Observer observer)
    {
        this.machineObservers.Remove(observer);
    }
    public void NotifyAllObservers(VendingMachineLog log)
    {
        foreach (Observer observer in this.machineObservers)
            observer.Update(log);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Unique Items: {0}, Total Items: {1}, Total Sales: {2}, Machine Bank: {3}",
            machineItems.Count, GetTotalMachineItems(), saleRecords.Count, machineBank.ToString("C"));
    }
}
```

**Item.cs, ItemFood.cs, ItemDrink.cs, ItemMakerType.cs**

```
public abstract class Item : ICloneable
{
    private static int totalItemCount = 0;

    protected readonly int itemID;
    protected readonly string itemName;
    protected readonly ItemMakerType.Value itemMaker;
    protected readonly double itemPrice;

    public Item(string itemName, ItemMakerType.Value itemMaker, double itemPrice)
    {
        this.itemID = totalItemCount++;
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.itemMaker = itemMaker;
        this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
    }
    public Item(Item item)
    {
        this.itemID = item.itemID;
        this.itemName = item.itemName;
        this.itemMaker = item.itemMaker;
        this.itemPrice = item.itemPrice;
    }

    public int ItemID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemID;
        }
    }
    public string ItemName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemName;
        }
    }
    public ItemMakerType.Value ItemMaker
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemMaker;
        }
    }
    public double ItemPrice
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemPrice;
        }
    }

    public static int TotalItems()
    {
        return totalItemCount;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("[Item Details] ID: {0}, Name: {1}, Maker: {2}, Price: {3}",
            this.itemID, this.itemName, this.itemMaker.ToString(), itemPrice.ToString("C"));
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Item castedItem;
        try
        {
            castedItem = (Item)obj;
            return this.itemID == castedItem.itemID;
        }
        catch { }
        return false;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.itemID;
    }

    public abstract Object Clone();
}
public class ItemFood : Item, IEatable
{
    protected int packCapacity;

    public ItemFood(string itemName, ItemMakerType.Value itemMaker, int packCapacity, double itemPrice)
        : base(itemName, itemMaker, itemPrice)
    {
        this.packCapacity = packCapacity;
    }
    public ItemFood(ItemFood itemFood) :
        base(itemFood)
    {
        this.packCapacity = itemFood.packCapacity;
    }

    public int PackCapacity
    {
        get
        {
            return this.packCapacity;
        }
    }

    public void Eat()
    {
        this.packCapacity = 0;
    }

    public override Object Clone()
    {
        return new ItemFood(this);
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("[FOOD] ID: {0}, Name: {1}, Maker: {2}, Price: {3}",
            this.itemID, string.Format("{0} ({1}g)", this.itemName, this.packCapacity), this.itemMaker, this.itemPrice.ToString("C"));
    }
}
public class ItemDrink : Item, IDrinkable
{
    protected int canCapacity;

    public ItemDrink(string itemName, ItemMakerType.Value itemMaker, int canCapacity, double itemPrice)
        : base(itemName, itemMaker, itemPrice)
    {
        this.canCapacity = canCapacity;
    }
    public ItemDrink(ItemDrink itemDrink) :
        base(itemDrink)
    {
        this.canCapacity = itemDrink.canCapacity;
    }

    public int CanCapacity
    {
        get
        {
            return this.canCapacity;
        }
    }
    public void Drink()
    {
        this.canCapacity = 0;
    }

    public override Object Clone()
    {
        return new ItemDrink(this);
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("[DRINK] ID: {0}, Name: {1}, Maker: {2}, Price: {3}",
            this.itemID, string.Format("{0} ({1}ml)", this.itemName, this.canCapacity), this.itemMaker, this.itemPrice.ToString("C"));
    }
}
public static class ItemMakerType
{
    public enum Value
    {
        CocaCola, PepsiCo, Faygo, Toscana, Regions, Fritolay
    }
}
```

**ItemFactory.cs**

```
public sealed class ItemFactory
{
    private static Dictionary<string, Item> cachedItems = new Dictionary<string, Item>();

    private static void LoadCachedItems()
    {
        cachedItems.Add("Coca Cola 330", new ItemDrink("Coca Cola Can", ItemMakerType.Value.CocaCola, 330, 1.49));
        cachedItems.Add("Coca Cola 500", new ItemDrink("Coca Cola Bottle", ItemMakerType.Value.CocaCola, 500, 2.49));
        cachedItems.Add("Coca Cola Diet 330", new ItemDrink("Coca Cola Diet Can", ItemMakerType.Value.CocaCola, 330, 1.49));
        cachedItems.Add("Coca Cola Diet 500", new ItemDrink("Coca Cola Diet Bottle", ItemMakerType.Value.CocaCola, 500, 2.49));
        cachedItems.Add("Coca Cola Zero 330", new ItemDrink("Coca Cola Zero Can", ItemMakerType.Value.CocaCola, 330, 1.49));
        cachedItems.Add("Coca Cola Zero 500", new ItemDrink("Coca Cola Zero Bottle", ItemMakerType.Value.CocaCola, 500, 2.49));
        cachedItems.Add("Sprite 330", new ItemDrink("Sprite Can", ItemMakerType.Value.CocaCola, 330, 1.49));
        cachedItems.Add("Sprite 500", new ItemDrink("Sprite Bottle", ItemMakerType.Value.CocaCola, 500, 2.49));
        cachedItems.Add("Sprite Diet 330", new ItemDrink("Sprite Diet Can", ItemMakerType.Value.CocaCola, 330, 1.49));
        cachedItems.Add("Sprite Diet 500", new ItemDrink("Sprite Diet Bottle", ItemMakerType.Value.CocaCola, 500, 2.49));
        cachedItems.Add("Fanta 330", new ItemDrink("Fanta Can", ItemMakerType.Value.CocaCola, 330, 1.49));
        cachedItems.Add("Fanta 500", new ItemDrink("Fanta Bottle", ItemMakerType.Value.CocaCola, 500, 2.49));
        cachedItems.Add("Fuze Tea 330", new ItemDrink("Fuze Tea Can", ItemMakerType.Value.CocaCola, 330, 1.49));
        cachedItems.Add("Fuze Tea 500", new ItemDrink("Fuze Tea Bottle", ItemMakerType.Value.CocaCola, 500, 2.49));
        cachedItems.Add("Pepsi 330", new ItemDrink("Pepsi Can", ItemMakerType.Value.PepsiCo, 330, 1.29));
        cachedItems.Add("Pepsi 500", new ItemDrink("Pepsi Bottle", ItemMakerType.Value.PepsiCo, 500, 2.29));
        cachedItems.Add("Pepsi Max 330", new ItemDrink("Pepsi Max Can", ItemMakerType.Value.PepsiCo, 330, 1.29));
        cachedItems.Add("Pepsi Max 500", new ItemDrink("Pepsi Max Bottle", ItemMakerType.Value.PepsiCo, 500, 2.29));
        cachedItems.Add("Evian 500", new ItemDrink("Evian Bottle", ItemMakerType.Value.Regions, 500, 1.79));
        cachedItems.Add("Aqua Panna 500", new ItemDrink("Aqua Panna Bottle", ItemMakerType.Value.Toscana, 500, 1.69));

        cachedItems.Add("Lays Classic", new ItemFood("Lays Classic", ItemMakerType.Value.Fritolay, 300, 2.99));
        cachedItems.Add("Lays Barbecue", new ItemFood("Lays Barbecue", ItemMakerType.Value.Fritolay, 300, 3.0));
        cachedItems.Add("Lays Sour Cream & Onion", new ItemFood("Lays Sour Cream & Onion", ItemMakerType.Value.Fritolay, 300, 3.0));
    }
    public static Item GetItem(string key)
    {
        if (cachedItems.Count == 0)
            LoadCachedItems();
        return cachedItems.ContainsKey(key) ? (Item)cachedItems[key].Clone() : null;
    }
}
```

**IEatable.cs , IDrinkable.cs**

```
public interface IEatable
{
    // Simple interface that demonstrates actions for a specifit set of objects (by object type).
    void Eat();
}
public interface IDrinkable
{
    // Simple interface that demonstrates actions for a specifit set of objects (by object type).
    void Drink();
}
```

**Observer.cs, MachineScreenObserver.cs, MachineLoggerObserver.cs, ObserverCommands.cs**

```
public interface Observer
{
    void Update(VendingMachineLog log);
}
public sealed class MachineScreenObserver : Observer
{
    public void Update(VendingMachineLog log)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Machine Screen: {0}", log.LogMessage);
    }
}
public sealed class MachineLoggerObserver : Observer
{
    private List<VendingMachineLog> vendingMachineLogs;

    public MachineLoggerObserver()
    {
        this.vendingMachineLogs = new List<VendingMachineLog>();
    }

    public void PrintLastMachineLogs(int num)
    {
        foreach (VendingMachineLog log in vendingMachineLogs)
        {
            if (num-- > 0)
                return;

            Console.WriteLine(log);
        }
    }
    public void Update(VendingMachineLog log)
    {
        this.vendingMachineLogs.Add(log);
        Console.WriteLine("Machine Logger: {0}", log.LogMessage);
    }
}
public interface ObserverCommands
{
    void RegisterObserver(Observer observer);
    void UnregisterObserver(Observer observer);
    void NotifyAllObservers(VendingMachineLog log);
}
```

**Record.cs, SaleRecord.cs**

```
public abstract class Record
{
    protected readonly int recordID;
    protected readonly DateTime recordDate;
    protected readonly string recordMessage;

    public Record(int recordID, DateTime recordDate, string recordMessage)
    {
        this.recordID = recordID;
        this.recordDate = recordDate;
        this.recordMessage = recordMessage;
    }

    public int RecordID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.recordID;
        }
    }
    public DateTime RecordDate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.recordDate;
        }
    }
    public string RecordMessage
    {
        get
        {
            return this.recordMessage;
        }
    }
}
public sealed class SaleRecord : Record
{
    private static int totalSaleRecords = 0;

    private readonly Item saleItem;
    private readonly double amountPaid;

    public SaleRecord(DateTime recordDate, string recordMessage, Item saleItem, double amountPaid) :
        base(totalSaleRecords++, recordDate, recordMessage)
    {
        this.saleItem = saleItem;
        this.amountPaid = amountPaid;
    }

    public Item SaleItem
    {
        get
        {
            return this.saleItem;
        }
    }
    public double AmountPaid
    {
        get
        {
            return this.amountPaid;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("[Sale Record] ID: {0}, Date: {1}, Item Sold: {2}, Sale Amount: {3}",
            this.recordID, this.recordDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"), this.saleItem.ItemName, this.saleItem.ItemPrice);
    }
}
```

**VendingMachineLog.cs**

```
public class VendingMachineLog
{
    private static int totalVendingMachineLogs = 0;

    protected readonly int logID;
    protected readonly DateTime logDate;
    protected readonly string logMessage;

    public VendingMachineLog(string logMessage)
    {
        this.logID = totalVendingMachineLogs++;
        this.logDate = DateTime.Now;
        this.logMessage = logMessage;
    } 
    public VendingMachineLog(DateTime logDate, string logMessage)
    {
        this.logID = totalVendingMachineLogs++;
        this.logDate = logDate;
        this.logMessage = logMessage;
    }

    public int LogID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.logID;
        }
    }
    public DateTime LogDate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.logDate;
        }
    }
    public string LogMessage
    {
        get
        {
            return this.logMessage;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("[Log] ID: {0}, Date: {1}, Message: {2}",
            this.logID, this.logDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"), this.logMessage);
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
class Program
{
    static VendingMachine vendingMachine;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        vendingMachine = VendingMachine.GetInstance();
        vendingMachine.RegisterObserver(new MachineLoggerObserver());
        vendingMachine.RegisterObserver(new MachineScreenObserver());

        PrintColored("- Initialized Vending Machine.", ConsoleColor.Cyan);
        RequestUserAction();
    }
    static void RequestUserAction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What action would you like to use?\n1 - Print Machine Info, 2 - Print 5 Last Sale Records, 3 - Refill Machine, 4 - Purchase a Product\nHINT: Type EXIT to disconnect from the system.");
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (userInput)
        {
            case "1":
                PrintColored(vendingMachine.ToString(), ConsoleColor.Green);
                break;
            case "2":
                DisplaySaleRecords();
                break;
            case "3":
                vendingMachine.RefillItems();
                //
                break;
            case "4":
                ProductPurchase();
                break;
            case "EXIT":
                Environment.Exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        RequestUserAction(); 
    }
    static void DisplaySaleRecords()
    {
        List<SaleRecord> saleRecords = vendingMachine.GetLastSaleRecords(5);

        if (saleRecords == null || saleRecords.Count == 0)
        {
            PrintColored("There are currently no sale records to present.", ConsoleColor.Red);
            return; ;
        }

        foreach(SaleRecord saleRecord in saleRecords)
            PrintColored(saleRecord.ToString(), ConsoleColor.DarkYellow);
    }
    static void ProductPurchase()
    {
        Item requestedItem = null;
        string userInputString = string.Empty;
        int userInputInt;
        double userInputDouble;

        if (vendingMachine.MachineItems.Count == 0)
        {
            PrintColored("[ERROR] This vending machine does not have any items in stock.", ConsoleColor.Red);
            return;
        }

        PrintColored("Select the item you would like to purchase (Item ID).", ConsoleColor.Cyan);
        Console.WriteLine("HINT: Type EXIT in order to return to the previous menu.");
        PrintColored("Available Machine Items:", ConsoleColor.Cyan);
        foreach (Item item in vendingMachine.MachineItems.Keys)
        {
            PrintColored(string.Format("{0} [IN STOCK: {1}]", item.ToString(), vendingMachine.MachineItems[item]), 
                ConsoleColor.DarkGreen);
        }

        userInputString = Console.ReadLine();

        if (userInputString == "EXIT")
            return;

        if (!int.TryParse(userInputString, out userInputInt))
        {
            PrintColored("[ERROR] Invalid input.", ConsoleColor.Red);
            ProductPurchase();
            return;
        }

        foreach (Item item in vendingMachine.MachineItems.Keys)
        {
            if (item.ItemID == userInputInt)
            {
                requestedItem = item;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (requestedItem == null)
        {
            PrintColored("[ERROR] No such item in the vending machine. Please try again.", ConsoleColor.Red);
            ProductPurchase();
            return;
        }

        if (vendingMachine.GetItemStock(requestedItem) == 0)
        {
            PrintColored("[ERROR] Item is out of stock.", ConsoleColor.Red);
            ProductPurchase();
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(requestedItem);
        Console.WriteLine("How much money are you paying?");
        userInputString = Console.ReadLine();

        if (!Double.TryParse(userInputString, out userInputDouble))
        {
            PrintColored("[ERROR] Invalid input.", ConsoleColor.Red);
            ProductPurchase();
            return;
        }
        if (userInputDouble < requestedItem.ItemPrice)
        {
            PrintColored("[ERROR]  Item price is higher than the paid amount.", ConsoleColor.Red);
            ProductPurchase();
            return;
        }

        vendingMachine.SellItem(requestedItem, userInputDouble);

        string recordMessage = string.Format("[Vending Machine]: Item has been successfully sold (Paid: {0}, Returned: {1}).",
                userInputDouble.ToString("C"), (userInputDouble - requestedItem.ItemPrice).ToString("C"));

        SaleRecord saleRecord = new SaleRecord(DateTime.Now, recordMessage, requestedItem, userInputDouble);
        vendingMachine.AddSaleRecord(saleRecord);
        PrintColored(recordMessage, ConsoleColor.Green);
    }
    static void PrintColored(string text, ConsoleColor color)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = color;
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}
```

I've tried to keep the class methods as simple as possible, and handled all the validations in Program.cs.
I would be glad to receive any sort of feedback regarding my code and style of writing.

Answer (score 7):

This isn't a pattern you typically see in the .Net languages.

> ```
> public void RegisterObserver(Observer observer)
> {
>     this.machineObservers.Add(observer);
> }
> public void UnregisterObserver(Observer observer)
> {
>     this.machineObservers.Remove(observer);
> }
> public void NotifyAllObservers(VendingMachineLog log)
> {
>     foreach (Observer observer in this.machineObservers)
>         observer.Update(log);
> }
> ```

But why? *Observables/Observers are a really useful pattern?!*

You don't ever see anyone implementing Observers by hand because the language natively supports the pattern via [Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx). Way back before VB6 the Microsoft languages had this pattern built into not just the language, but into the philosophy of how these languages are meant to work at their core.

There's nothing actually wrong with your implementation, but using events would be a much more idiomatic way to code it.

Comment: I'm aware of the Events the .NET framework offers, however working with Observers was more of a practice for me. Thanks for your feedback regardless.

Answer (score 5):

## Design

### Cloning the items

It looks like we are conflating the description of an item (Name, Maker, Price) with consuming the item. It looks like we could separate the two concepts into

```
 public class ItemDescription
 {
    public ItemDescription(string name, Maker maker, decimal price, int size)
    {
        Name = name;
        Maker = maker;
        Price = price;
        Size = size;
    }

    public string Name { get;}
    public ItemMaker Maker { get; }
    public decimal Price { get; }
    public int Size { get; }
}


public abstract class Item 
{
    private readonly ItemDescription description;

    protected Item(ItemDescription description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public string Name => this.description.Name;

    public ItemMaker Maker => this.description.Maker;

    public decimal Price => this.description.Price;

    protected int Size => this.description.Size;

}

public class Food : Item, IEatable
{
    public Food(ItemDescription description)
      :base(description)
    {
        PackCapacity = description.Size;
    }

    public int PackCapacity { get; private set; }

    public void Eat()
    {
        PackCapacity = 0;
    }
}
```

The factory becomes a bit more complicated because we need to create objects of different types rather than just cloning an item but that is the sort of thing for which we have factories.

### Static Counter in Sales Records

Unless we are saying that either,

- the record ids are not really that important (we don't mind if we have duplicate numbers), or
- the vending machine is never going to be restarted

then using a static counter in the `SaleRecord` for the record id is dubious.

## Code Comments

### Data types

It is recommended that [decimal](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) is used for money values rather than doubles. [Binary floating point and .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx).

The `Stack` for getting the last `n` sale records seems move convoluted.
the following would give the same result

```
private readonly IList<SaleRecord> saleRecords;

public IEnumerable<SaleRecord> GetLastSaleRecords(int num)
{
    var skipCount= Math.Max(0, saleRecords.Count - num);
    return saleRecords.Skip(skipCount);
}
```

**Edit:**
If we do want to use the Stack then

```
public List<SaleRecord> GetLastSaleRecords(int num)
{
    return saleRecords.Take(num).ToList();
}
```

should suffice.

### Idioms

Auto-properties would be recommended for the public properties of `VendingMachine` where the property is a simple pass-through to the backing field

```
public decimal MachineBank { get; private set;}
public IDictionary<Item, int> MachineItems { get; }
```

**Note:** `MachineItems` is defined as `IDictionary` rather than `Dictionary`. We care about the contract (interface) not the implementation.

### Getting Items From Dictionary

`TryGetValue` has better performance than a `Contains` check.

```
public int GetItemStock(Item item)
{
    int count;
    if(!machineItems.TryGetValue(item, out count)) return -1;

    return count;
}
```

This can be more pithy with C#7.

### Linq is our friend

```
public int GetTotalMachineItems()
{
    return machineItems.Values.Sum();
}
```

### Minor

The convention for naming interfaces in C# is to [prefix the interface name with an 'I'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040(v=vs.100).aspx).  It may seem (be) arbitrary but does aid reading the code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. Much appreciated.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think there's a built in stack type.

Comment: @RubberDuck I'm unsure of the direction of your comment. The OP is using a (built in) stack to hold the SaleRecords but it is seems a very restrictive way of holding the records. Why use a Stack when a List will suffice?

Answer (score 0):

I think the name `machineBank` is misleading. It could be machineMoneySum for example.

BTW, maybe we do not really need the "machine" part, since we are already inside the `VendingMachine` class. This applies to the other properties as well.

---

When `GetLastSaleRecords` is called with a negative number (or even zero), should it really return `null`? Maybe it is more appropriate to throw an exception, if your general principle is "my methods accept only correct arguments".

In any case, when the return type is a Collection, it is generally suggested in .NET to return an empty one instead of `null`. The positive effect is, the caller will never need to bother checking for a `null` in case of a Collection.

---

In the `Equals()` of `Item`, instead of

```
castedItem = (Item)obj;
```

and catching the exception, you can simply

```
castedItem = Item as obj;
```

and check if the result is not null.

BTW, I find neat writing the `Equals()` like this:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType())
    {
        return false;
    }

    return Equals((Item)obj);
}

public bool Equals(Item item)
{
    return itemID == item.itemID;
}
```

Each of the two functions really does one thing. :)

The first function is standard for all classes other than the type in the cast. Notice that we know this cast is safe, because we checked the type shortly before.

---

What is the unit of measurement in `packCapacity` and `canCapacity` in `ItemFood` and `ItemDrink` respectively? It is a readability plus to put it either directly in the variable name, e.g. `packCapacityGrams`, or in a comment.